# Sum of a word array not storing in another word array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, addressing-mode

*The task assigned to me twas to write an assembly program that finds the sum of three 8-bits values and places it in memory at location SUMS. Then compute sum of three word variable, and place it in memory at location SUMS + 2. Use the following data:

```
BYTE_ARRAY DB 10H,20H,30H
WORD_ARRAY DW 1000H,2000H,3000H
SUMS DW 0,0*
```

My problem is that the following code gives me an error

```
mov sums,al
```

I understand that one is a 16 bit address and the other is 8 bit address but is there any other way to get around it?

EDIT:

Complete code:

```
    org 100h

.data 
byte_array db 10h,20h,30h
word_array dw 1000h,2000h,3000h


sums dw 0,0

.code

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov bx,offset byte_array
mov al,[bx]
inc bx
add al,[bx]
inc bx
add al,[bx]
mov si,offset sums
mov [si],al

mov bx,offset word_array
mov ax,[bx]
add ax,[bx+2]
add ax,[bx+4]
mov [bx+6], ax





ret
```

My only problem that remains is that i do not understand the meaning of SUMS + 2. What is the questions asking me to do?

Comment: no this is as far as i have gotten. i have tackled only trying add to 3 8 bit values. the rest of the question is untouched.

Answer (score 1):

`al` is 8 bits.

`sum` is 16 bits.

so they have conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
SUMS DW 0,0
mov sums,al
```

As you declared your array being of word size, your operand should match that.

```
mov sums, ax
```

Comment: in addition, the task to store sum of three word variable, and place it in memory at location SUMS + 2 will be achieved through the means of pointers? correct?

Comment: That could be done, and makes sense. Not strictly neccessary for this though. And as the code is missing, I was not commenting on that part.